# spring transaction rollback with @Transaction annotation using jdbcTemplates

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

Here is an example where I am using JdbcTemplate. My question `doMultipleCalls()` fail at step 3 due to runTimeException, will everything gets rolledback.
I have `@Transactional` annotation only to `doMultipleCalls` but not to others. Is the same transaction session shared across all of them?. If not how to pass same transaction session across?

```
@Component
public class MyRespository {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate template

@Transactional
public void doMutlipleCalls() {
   callUpdate(); //1
   callInsert(); //2
   callDelete(); //3
}

callUpdate() {
  template.query(...)
}

callInsert() {
   template.query(...)
} 

callDelete() {
   template.query(..)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the same transaction session shared across all of them?

Yes. The transaction is begun prior to entering the `doMultipleCalls()` method and is completed once it returns.

Comment: so that would mean if any of the method call inside `doMultipleCalls` (say 3) throws RunTimeException,  call 1 and 2 are rolled back right?

Comment: Right. Any unchecked exception will cause the transaction to be rolled back

Answer (score 1):

When you use spring jdbc with transactional, it acts in the same manner as it does with jpa. Your actions are wrapped under the same transaction.

Check this [article](http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-jdbc-example).